# NuGet when sharing projects between solutions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have several solutions that share certain common projects, such as one that contains all the necesary things to access my data model.

[image: Solution Explorer situation]

The actual problem is that trying to install packages with NuGet in one proyect with dependencies (ex. Iesi.Collections), creates a reference to the dll in the current solution directory and not in the proyect directory. Then, when I try to go to another of my solutions, the shared project fails to compile (because of the missing assembly).

[image: First path reference]
[image: Second path reference]

I have searched all around for using NuGet in shared projects between solutions in an independent way.

So the question is... How can I manage obtain an independent behaviour and references between solutions in NuGet?

Comment: did you actually name your projects using a bunch of leading spaces?

Comment: @WimOmbelets it's called privacy... there are no spaces in any project name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this issue is to add a `.nuget\NuGet.config` file to all solutions, and set the `repositoryPath` to a decicated local folder.

From [this link](https://chrismay.org/2016/10/12/visual-studio-2015-nuget-config-repositorypath/), assuming you're using VS2015:

1. Create a .nuget folder in the root of the solution (on the file system) (if you're having trouble creating a `.nuget` folder using windows explorer, you can do so by entering `.nuget.` instead)
2. Inside that folder, create a file NuGet.config.
3. In Visual Studio 2015, right click on the solution and add a new solution directory called “.nuget”
4. Right click on that folder and select to add a new an existing file and select the NuGet.config file created in (2).
5. Add content like this inside the NuGet.config file:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <configuration>
>   <solution>
>     <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
>   </solution>
>   <config>
>     <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\..\..\NugetPackages" />
>   </config>
> </configuration>
> ```

6. Restart Visual Studio

Note that you'll have to fix existing references, for instance by removing and then adding all packages again.

I personally use an absolute path for the packages, since not all of my solutions are in the same folder hierarchy - if you're in a team you might want to discuss this first.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, although I don't know why this is not directly provided by the vendor. Seems it doesn't work for VS 2017, so what should I do about it?

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach to this problem is modifying package reference path in `.csproj` file like by utilising `$(SolutionDir)` macro - this will point the reference to correct directory in both solutions:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <HintPath>
            $(SolutionDir)packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
        </HintPath>
    </Reference>
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, worked like a charm.